# PostgresSQL production table database has capital letter

Tags: php, postgresql, quoted-identifier

may I know how can I select my database if all the column has all capital letters. I run this query and it works

```
SELECT public.countryhomes."PH" from public.countryhomes where public.countryhomes."Read_Datetime" = '2022-09-21 10:15:00'
```

However when I tried to put inside my PHP code it doesn't work. I run like this

```
$sqlx = pg_query($dbconn, 'SELECT public.countryhomes."PH" from public.countryhomes where public.countryhomes."Read_Datetime"  = '.$date.'');
```

When I tried to echo the sqlx, it returned with error saying syntax error near the quot and return something like this

```
SELECT public.countryhomes."PH" from public.countryhomes where public.countryhomes."Read_Datetime"  = 2022-09-21 10:15:00
```

means, it didnt read my quotes near the datetime. Does anyone know how to fix this? Because I am not allowed to change the database since its in production. Please help

Comment: hi, note date literals need to be enclosed in quotes

Comment: @jspcal hi yes, I did. when I run the query inside my db it works but when I want to put inside my php code  `$sqlx = pg_query($dbconn, 'SELECT public.countryhomes."PH" from public.countryhomes where public.countryhomes."Read_Datetime"  = '.$date.'');
`  it doesnt work anymore. Seems like it didnt read my  quotes

Comment: You have to escape some quotes.